# Combine Multiple Fields in QuerySelectField with Lambda & NoneTypes

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, wtforms

Utilizing Flask, SQLAlchemy, WTForms and [WTForms-SqlAlchemy](https://wtforms-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/wtforms_sqlalchemy/) to leverage the QuerySelectField type.

mdm_forms.py:

```
def readiness_level_details():
    return ReadinessLevelDetail.query.order_by('readiness_level_type_id')

class ReadinessLevelAssessmentForm(FlaskForm):
       activity = QuerySelectField('Activity', validators=[DataRequired()], allow_blank=False, query_factory=activities, get_label='name')
       readiness_level_detail = QuerySelectField('RL', validators=[DataRequired()], allow_blank=False, query_factory=readiness_level_details, get_label=lambda rld: f"{'' if rld.readiness_level_category.name is None else rld.readiness_level_category.name}" )
       assessment_date = DateField('Assessment Date', validators=[DataRequired()])
       justification = TextAreaField('Justification') 
       assessor = QuerySelectField('Assessor', allow_blank=True, query_factory=users, get_label='email')
       submit = SubmitField('Save')
```

Specifics from Model.py

```
class ReadinessLevelDetail(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'readiness_level_detail'
    readiness_level_category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('readiness_level_category.id'))

    # Direct Model Relationships
    readiness_level_category = relationship("ReadinessLevelCategory", back_populates="readiness_level_details") 

class ReadinessLevelCategory(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'readiness_level_category'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) 
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    abbreviation = db.Column(db.String(255)) 
    description = db.Column(db.Text) 
    sort_order = db.Column(db.Integer) 
    
    # Indirect Model Relationships
    readiness_level_details = relationship("ReadinessLevelDetail", back_populates="readiness_level_category")
```

My specific problem is coming from this line:

```
readiness_level_detail = QuerySelectField('RL', validators=[DataRequired()], allow_blank=False, query_factory=readiness_level_details, get_label=lambda rld: f"{'' if rld.readiness_level_category.name is None else rld.readiness_level_category.name}" )
```

Specifically:

```
get_label=lambda rld: f"{'' if rld.readiness_level_category.name is None else rld.readiness_level_category.name}"
```

I get an error regardless of how I write this lambda. There will always be a NoneType associated with the Category. I simplified the f string but it will eventually use what is displayed along with several other values to concatenate a string for the label on the drop down.

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

Specific section from the documentation states this:

> Specify get_label to customize the label associated with each option.
> If a string, this is the name of an attribute on the model object to
> use as the label text. If a one-argument callable, this callable will
> be passed model instance and expected to return the label text.
> Otherwise, the model object’s **str** will be used.

I have plenty of other fields built with the following format, but there is no allowance for a NoneType:

```
get_label=lambda s: '%s (%s %s)' % (s.team.name, s.organization_office.organization.abbreviation, s.organization_office.office.name))
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can pull multiple columns from related tables with some values being NoneType and build the label? I basically need to check for NoneType and have been unsuccessful inside of the lambda here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this was me being dumb. Can't check an attribute named "name" on a NoneType object. Face palm for the day.